# SoftLayer_ObjectMask for SoftLayer_Network_Gateway_Vlan::getObject

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I would like to use SoftLayer_Network_Gateway_Vlan::getObject in Python in order to check whether a VLAN is already attached to a gateway before using createObject.
I have no problem to use createObject with such a piece of code:

```
    obj = {'bypassFlag':False, 'id':None, 'networkGatewayId':module.params['gateway_id'], 'networkVlanId':module.params['vlan_id']}
    try:
        res = env['Network_Gateway_Vlan'].createObject(obj)
    except SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
        module.fail_json(msg=e.faultString)
```

But I don't know how to write a piece of code to retrieve the list of VLANs that are already attached to a gateway :(

If somebody has a sample about using the getObject method it would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do not use just the method [getNetworkVlan](https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Gateway_Vlan/getNetworkVlan)? the method returns the VLAN associated to the SoftLayer_Network_Gateway_Vlan.

but if you wanna use the getObject method this is the mask you need to use:

```
env['SoftLayer_Network_Gateway_Vlan'].getObject(id= myIdGatewayVlan, mask= "mask[networkVlan]")
```

But I think is better to use this one:

```
env['SoftLayer_Account'].getNetworkGateways( mask="mask[insideVlans[networkVlan]]")
```

that will list all the gateways in your account and its associated vlans.

or even better you can use a filter to check if the VLAN is already set in any 
SoftLayer_Network_Gateway_Vlan

```
env['SoftLayer_Account'].getNetworkGateways( mask="mask[insideVlans[networkVlan]]", filter={"networkGateways":{"insideVlans":{"networkVlan":{"id":{"operation":1319435}}}}})
```

note: replace 1319435 with the ID of the VLAN you wanna check
If the request above returns empty so the VLAN is not attached to any SoftLayer_Network_Gateway_Vlan

Comment: Your third proposition was exactly what I needed, thanks a lot!