# SoftLayer VLAN disassociate / detach

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I would like to use the API to disassociate a specific VLAN from a gateway.
It can be attached with the following piece of code:

```
import SoftLayer
from SoftLayer.CLI import environment

env = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env()
obj = {'bypassFlag':False, 'id':None, 'networkGatewayId':65884, 'networkVlanId':944459}

res = env['Network_Gateway_Vlan'].createObject(obj)
```

But when I try to use method deleteObject (with same data) when the VLAN is attached of course, I get the following error:

```
>>> res = env['Network_Gateway_Vlan'].deleteObject(obj)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/lochou/GitHub/ansible-dist/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 390, in call_handler
    return self(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/lochou/GitHub/ansible-dist/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 358, in call
    return self.client.call(self.name, name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/lochou/GitHub/ansible-dist/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 261, in call
    return self.transport(request)
  File "/Users/lochou/GitHub/ansible-dist/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/transports.py", line 215, in __call__
    raise _ex(ex.faultCode, ex.faultString)
SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError: SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception): Object does not exist to execute method on. (SoftLayer_Network_Gateway_Vlan::deleteObject)
```

I don't understand what I missed here :(
The data seem correct since if I retry createObject I get the meaningful error below:

```
>>> res = env['Network_Gateway_Vlan'].createObject(obj)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/lochou/GitHub/ansible-dist/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 390, in call_handler
    return self(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/lochou/GitHub/ansible-dist/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 358, in call
    return self.client.call(self.name, name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/lochou/GitHub/ansible-dist/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 261, in call
    return self.transport(request)
  File "/Users/lochou/GitHub/ansible-dist/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/transports.py", line 215, in __call__
    raise _ex(ex.faultCode, ex.faultString)
SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError: SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Public): VLAN ID 944459 is an inside VLAN for gateway gw001-par (#65884)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need only send the id of the object that you want to delete:

```
e.g:

env['Network_Gateway_Vlan'].deleteObject(id=theIdofTheObject)
```

The create method will return you the newly created object with its id so you can do this:

```
res = env['Network_Gateway_Vlan'].createObject(obj)
env['Network_Gateway_Vlan'].deleteObject(id=res["id"])
```

Comment: OK, thank you very much Nelson.  Just tested it and it works fine.  But this new id is not the NetworkVlanId.  How can I get it when the VLAN has been associated with the Web GUI, let's say?  Or by script, but another one, where "res" has not been kept?

Comment: It is not the ID is gonna be always a new ID and I've already answered your question on this forum https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49198871/softlayer-objectmask-for-softlayer-network-gateway-vlangetobject

Comment: Sorry Nelson.  It's probably obvious for you, but I'm only a beginner here...  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think the following piece of code does the job of retrieving the right id (different from the VLAN id) but I'm not proud of it:

```
vlans = env['SoftLayer_Account'].getNetworkGateways(mask="mask[insideVlans[networkVlan]]", filter={"networkGateways":{"insideVlans":{"networkVlan":{"id":{"operation":vlan_id}}}}})
if vlans:
    for i in range(len(vlans[0]['insideVlans'])):
        insideVlan = vlans[0]['insideVlans'][i]
        if insideVlan['networkVlan']['id'] == vlan_id:
            try:
                res = env['Network_Gateway_Vlan'].deleteObject(id=insideVlan['id'])
            except SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
                module.fail_json(msg=e.faultString)
```

There's probably something smarter though!